# Box2D/Farseer conveyor belts - character gets squeezed into ceiling

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, farseer

I have implemented moving my character using `Contact.TangentSpeed` (something similar to this: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/conveyor-belts):

```
foreach (var contact in GroundContacts)
{
    contact.Contact.TangentSpeed = -MaximumVelocity;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I move my character to a place like this:
[image]

It moves into the walls instead of stopping. If I press character with `ApplyForce`, everything is ok though.

**How to make it stop instead of moving into the wall, without explicitly checking for previously described situation?**

I think it might be important to note, that the black bodies are static.

Comment: Hmm... this method was always kind of a hack. Is that dynamic body a fixed rotation body? I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: @iforce2d It is a fixed rotation body. And as far as I know, the initial value of TangentSpeed is always 0, and is meant to be used explicitly for conveyor belts (Farseer's source comments `TangentSpeed` with `Get or set the desired tangent speed for a conveyor belt behavior. In meters per second.` - so it does not seem to be a hack no more :). I fixed the problem with explicit checking though :)